# Unable to convert pyodbc cursor.execute results into a dataframe

Tags: python, sql, pandas, odbc

I tried to run SQL with pyodbc but was not able to convert the results into data framework. I got the error message  -
ValueError: Shape of passed values is (47, 1), indices imply (47, 3).

For names, I got a list of string
['ID', 'Country', 'Date']

For rows, I got a list of tuples like
[('A1', 'USA', datetime.date(2011, 12, 31)), ('A1', 'USA', datetime.date(2020, 4, 21)), ...('A3','Cananda', datetime.date(2001, 2, 11))]

The query for the same table works fine if I use pandas.read_sql. I would get 47 rows and 3 columns instead of 1 column. However, I need to use cursor.execute due to the need of incorporating a local list for SQL. The actual list is much longer containing hundreds of ids. Any ideas on how to convert the results?

```
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd

conn = pyodbc.connect("DSN=dsn")
conn.setdecoding(pyodbc.SQL_CHAR, encoding='utf-8')
conn.setencoding(encoding="utf-8")

cursor = conn.cursor()

list_id = ["A1","A2","A3"]
placeholders = ",".join("?" * len(list_id))
sql = "select * from table Where ID in (%s)"  % placeholders
cursor.execute(sql, list_id)

names = [ x[0] for x in cursor.description]
rows = cursor.fetchall()

cursor.close()
conn.close()

df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns =names)
df
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok. I figured it out. Only need to reshape the rows.

```
import pyodbc
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

conn = pyodbc.connect("DSN=dsn")
conn.setdecoding(pyodbc.SQL_CHAR, encoding='utf-8')
conn.setencoding(encoding="utf-8")

cursor = conn.cursor()

pid = ["P077856","P079661"]
placeholders = ",".join("?" * len(pid))
sql = "select PROJ_ID, ROLE_CODE from PROJECT.PROJECT_TEAM_V2 Where PROJ_ID in (%s)"  % placeholders
cursor.execute(sql, pid)

names = [ x[0] for x in cursor.description]
rows = cursor.fetchall()
rows = np.array(rows).reshape(47,3)

df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns =names)
df
```